# VBA Visual Studio: Select Specific marked text,copy it and paste tabstop

Tags: vba, text, textbox

I need to select a text (in a `textbox`) which begins witch some specific character like " or ; , after that the text must be pasted in an other `textbox`. `bBore` every line must be a `Tabstop`.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Please post some code that you tried and explain the problem with it. [Minimum complete verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Dim suchwort As String = a various nuber which has a maximum lengh of 18.
RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(suchwort) + suchwort.Length, ControlChars.Tab)`

Comment: Is there a way to choose this nuber (its an ID) and attach behind it a tabstop? The same for a textblock , but there must be the tabstop attached before every line